# Attaching unsaved Excel file to email

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have an Excel form for users to fill and send as an attachment (without having to save it locally on their computer).

The code works.

```
Dim Names()
Names = Array("testmail@gmail.com")
ActiveWorkbook.SendMail _
Recipients:=Names(), _
Subject:="Test subject"
```

I would like the email just to be created and not sent until the users have attached an additional file (found on their local computer).

I wrote the following code:

```
Dim olapp As Object
Dim olmail As Object
Dim wb As Workbook
Set olapp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set olmail = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

With olmail
.To = "testmail@gmail.com"
.Subject = "Test Subject"
.Body = ""
.Attachments.Add wb.FullName
.Display
```

My problem is that only the latest saved copy will be attached to the created email, and since the users will not have the form/Excel file stored locally on their computer, an empty form (or the last saved form) will be attached to the email.

Is there any way for an email to be created, with a copy of the workbook, but not to send it?

Comment: Yes. You can save the latest version of file (as filled out by the user) to their `C:\` or even a path on a network folder. Attach it to the email, then delete the saved file.

Comment: If you're late-binding the Outlook object model, then the `olMailItem` constant/enum isn't defined and is therefore treated as any undeclared variable, i.e. an implicit `Variant` that contains `vbEmpty`, which implicitly converts to `0`. If that code compiles without a reference to the Outlook type library, then `Option Explicit` isn't specified, which means more problems are to be expected. If Outlook *is* referenced, then just `New` up the `Outlook.Application` and declare it `As Outlook.Application` instead of working with late-bound `Object`. You'll get IntelliSense, too!

Answer (score 0):

i tried this one-liner in the immediate window and it managed to send an unsaved file: `Application.Workbooks("Book2").SendMail("my.email@company.com","Test Subject")` you can use wb from your code instead of Application.Workbooks("Book2") in my example. Note that this will send the email, without the possibility to edit it.